# Custom protocol is not working in swift

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift, protocols

I have two `UIViewController`s HomeViewController and ArrangeViewController.

In ArrangeViewController, I have this code

```
import UIKit

protocol ArrangeClassProtocol
{
    func recieveThearray(language : NSMutableArray)
}

class ArrangeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { // class "ArrangeViewController" has no initializer

    var ArrangeClassDelegateObject : ArrangeClassProtocol?

    // Global Variables Goes Here
    var languageNamesArray: NSMutableArray = ["Tamil","English"]
    var userDefaults : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var tempArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    // Outlets Goes Here
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Saving the Array in a UserDefaultObject
            if userDefaults.boolForKey("languageNamesArrayuserDefaults")
            {
                tempArray = userDefaults.objectForKey("languageNamesArrayuserDefaults") as NSMutableArray
            }
            else
            {
                tempArray = languageNamesArray
            }

        self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero

         // TableView Reordering
        self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }


    // Delegate Methods of the UITableView
     func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return tempArray.count
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Arrange", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ArrangeTableViewCell
        cell.languageName.font = UIFont(name: "Proxima Nova", size: 18)
        cell.languageName.text = tempArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSString
        cell.showsReorderControl = true
        return cell
    }

    // Delegate Methods for dragging the cell
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle
    {

        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath!, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath!)
    {
        var stringToMove = tempArray.objectAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row) as NSString
        tempArray .removeObjectAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
        tempArray .insertObject(stringToMove, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath!, toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> NSIndexPath!
    {
        let section:AnyObject = tempArray .objectAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.section)
        var sectionCount = tempArray.count as NSInteger
        if sourceIndexPath.section != proposedDestinationIndexPath.section
        {
            var rowinSourceSection:NSInteger =  (sourceIndexPath.section > proposedDestinationIndexPath.section) ? 0 : (sectionCount-1)

            return NSIndexPath(forRow: rowinSourceSection, inSection: sourceIndexPath.row)


        }
        else if proposedDestinationIndexPath.row >= sectionCount
        {

            return NSIndexPath(forRow: (sectionCount-1), inSection: sourceIndexPath.row)
        }


        return proposedDestinationIndexPath
    }

    // Creating the HomeViewController Object and presenting the ViewController
    @IBAction func closeButtonClicked(sender: UIButton)
    {
        userDefaults.setObject(tempArray, forKey: "languageNamesArrayuserDefaults")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
        ArrangeClassDelegateObject?.recieveThearray(languageNamesArray)
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

In the HomeViewController, I this code.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, ArrangeClassProtocol {

   var ArrangeClassObject : ArrangeViewController = ArrangeViewController() // ArrangeViewController is Constructible with ()
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.ArrangeClassObject.ArrangeClassDelegateObject = self
}

func recieveThearray(language: NSMutableArray)
    {
        println(language)
    }
}
```

I wanted to access the Array that am passing from the ArrangeViewController. But its showing errors  that I commented out near to the statements. I also used the optional values with the HomeViewController, It also showing error and crashes the app. Please somebody help to figure this out.

I got this idea by a github post. In that project he used one `UIViewController` and one another swift class. That is also possible for me. But i want to work it out with these two `UIViewController`s.

Comment: I can't reproduce your "Class "ArrangeViewController" has no initialisers" error. Are you on the latest beta, beta 4? Do you have any other properties? Do you get more information about which property is causing the error when you click on the error (if I force your error by adding an uninitialised property, I get prompted with a "fix-it" that tells me which property is the problem.) Can you post a complete, short example that reproduces your error?

Comment: (Also, your second error is simply a side effect of your first, assuming your error message actually reads "ArrangeViewController is **not** Constructible with ()"... That's because Swift can't find a valid initialiser because your ArrangeViewController has been broken by whatever's causing the first error.)

Comment: @MattGibson Theres is no other option to see the errors. The xcode oly shows these two errors. I have no idea what to do. Can i initialise something.??

Comment: @MattGibson i am using xcode6-beta4

Comment: @MattGibson please flag the question noh? so that everyone can see it.. I really wanted to solve this thing.

Comment: Can you post enough of your ArrangeViewController to reproduce the problem? Do you have any other properties declared in it other than ArrangeClassDelegateObject and languageNamesArray? The best way of getting a question up-voted is to make it clear and provide enough code for people to paste the problem into their own Xcode and see the problem.

Comment: @MattGibson please have a look at this, I added more code.

Comment: @MattGibson I will try, just a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the new code. The problem that's creating your error message is here:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

If you change this code to:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView?
```

Then the compiler will stop complaining about the lack of an initialiser.

However, that's more a diagnostic tool than an actual fix for the problem, which is that you need an initialiser. I think what's going on is that up until you add an uninitialised property at your own class's level in the hierarchy, you're being provided with a default initialiser. At the point you add your uninitialised property, Swift will stop generating the default initialiser, and expect you to provide your own.

If you check the header for UIViewController, you'll find this advice:

```
/*
  The designated initializer. If you subclass UIViewController, you must call the super implementation of this
  method, even if you aren't using a NIB.  (As a convenience, the default init method will do this for you,
  and specify nil for both of this methods arguments.) In the specified NIB, the File's Owner proxy should
  have its class set to your view controller subclass, with the view outlet connected to the main view. If you
  invoke this method with a nil nib name, then this class' -loadView method will attempt to load a NIB whose
  name is the same as your view controller's class. If no such NIB in fact exists then you must either call
  -setView: before -view is invoked, or override the -loadView method to set up your views programatically.
*/
init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!)
```

So, perhaps just try:

```
init()  {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
```

...which should restore the functionality of the originally-provided initialiser. I'm guessing your IBOutlet will be properly "warmed up" from the Storyboard by the base class's initialiser, and you should again be able to construct the View Controller with an argumentless initialiser.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'm probably out on a bit of a limb here as far as my knowledge of how the initialisation of view controllers works, though. I'd wait until a few other people have had a chance to check out the question and get some more opinions. I've upvoted your question now you've posted enough code to reproduce the issue.